# The target path "" is a directory and not a file

Tags: c#, directory

I am trying to copy a file into another folder, here is my code.

```cs
private static void CopyDirectory(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    foreach (var sourceFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(source.FullName))
    {
        FileInfo file;

        if(IsAccesable(sourceFilePath, out file))
        {
            file.CopyTo(target.FullName); //ERROR HERE
        }
        else
        {
            //DO WORKAROUND
        }
    }

    foreach(var sourceSubDirectoryPath in Directory.GetDirectories(source.FullName))
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory;

        if(IsAccesable(sourceSubDirectoryPath, out directory))
        {
            var targetSubDictionary = target.CreateSubdirectory(Path.Combine(target.FullName, sourceSubDirectoryPath));
            CopyDirectory(directory, targetSubDictionary);
        }
        else
        {
            //DO WORKAROUND
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error message: The target path "" is a directory and not a file

Full sourcePath:

```
"c:\\Hypixel Bots Interface\\.gitattributes"
```

Full targetPath:

```
"C:\\Users\\wout\\source\\repos\\FileCloner\\FileCloner\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0\\Target\\Hypixel Bots Interface"
```

Comment: When you copy a file you have to tell it what file to copy to but you are giving it a Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file in your path. For example, create a file in your folder and name it test.txt an run again your code to verify if the error will disappear.

"C:\Users\wout\source\repos\FileCloner\FileCloner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Target\Hypixel Bots Interface\.gitattributes\test.txt"

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you want the targetPath to be a file name. You are just pointing to a folder.

```
"C:\\Users\\wout\\source\\repos\\FileCloner\\FileCloner\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0\\Target\\Hypixel Bots Interface\\.gitattributes"
```

That would be pointing to a new file in that directory

Comment: I want to put it in a folder and make a new file in the folder.

Comment: Yes. So at the end of the file path you need to add the file name like I did above. It will see that no file with that name exists so it will make a new one.

Comment: Help, it says that the path C:\\Users\\wout\\source\\repos\\FileCloner\\FileCloner\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0\\Target\\Hypixel Bots Interface does already exists.

Comment: If you wish to run it again you need to tell it to overwrite the file.

file.CopyTo(target.FullName, true)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.copyto?view=net-5.0

In the future please reference the official docs before asking questions.